# Laravel not finding IoC binding in controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a custom class `App/Http/Responder`, which had a few methods to build a specific JSON response back in my application. I want to test my controller in isolation, so I'm trying to inject my dependencies via the constructor.

My plan was to simply create a service provider, attach bind it to the `$app` and then, as per the docs, let it be automatically resolved:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('responder', function()
    {
        return new App\Http\Responder($this->app['cache'], $this->app['app'], new JsonResponse, $this->app['config']);
    });
}
```

I then add this to my `config/app.php`.

Okay, so now my Responder and it's dependancies are bound to the app, as `responder`.

Now I thought I'd be able to inject `Responder` into my controller constructor, and Laravel would be able to automatically resolve this from the IoC container:

```
class AreasController extends BaseController {

    protected $responder;

    public function __construct(Responder $responder)
    {
        $this->responder = $responder;
    }
```

However I get `Class Responser does not exist`.

The only way I can get it working, without using the `App::make()` Facade, is to inject the app into my controller:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application as App;

class AreasController extends BaseController {

    protected $app;

    public function __construct(App $app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
    }
```

I can then do `$this->app['responder']->method()`.

Obviously I'm missing something, but I want to keep away from using Facades in my app so I can test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to type hint classes to be resolved in the IOC container, you should bind the actual class name with namespace:

```
$this->app->bind('App\Http\Responder', function()
{
    return new App\Http\Responder($this->app['cache'], $this->app['app'], new JsonResponse, $this->app['config']);
});
```

Technically the container would still resolve this class, because it's a concrete class that can be found, but the way you're doing allows to inject other IOC-bound resources, which is a good practice.

Then, when you wish to have this class injected for you, type hint the full path to the class as you normally would:

```
use App\Http\Responder;

class AreasController extends BaseController {

    protected $responder;

    public function __construct(Responder $responder)
    {
        $this->responder = $responder;
    }
}
```

---

*Also, for what it's worth, your error indicates that you misspelled "Responder" as "Responser".*

Comment: Thanks... So now in my `Responder` class constructor, am I supposed to just do `__construct($cache, $app, $response, $config)`, because it seems to be throwing `Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $cache ]] in class App\Http\Responder`... Confused!

Comment: Make sure that you are registering your service provider, so that the IoC container knows to build it using your binding, and not automatically build the concrete class.

Comment: Ah silly me, changed the name of the binding! Thanks for taking the time though!